# Uncaught TypeError: map.downloadExport is not a function (angular 2 typescript)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, leaflet

Im getting the following error in my typescript class and cannot understand why. All I am doing is trying to call a helper function passing the token.

Error: post error: map.downloadExport is not a function

here is my code

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {MapService} from "../../../shared/leaflet/map.service";
import {GeocodingService} from "../../../shared/leaflet/geocoding.service";


import "leaflet-easybutton";

var leafletImage = require("leaflet-image/leaflet-image")

declare var downloadExport: any;

// import '../../../../leaflet_export.js';

@Component({
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  selector: 'Home',
  templateUrl: './app/components/tools/sketch/sketch.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app/components/tools/sketch/sketch.component.css' ],
  providers: [MapService, GeocodingService]

  })

  export class SketchComponent {

   public vtLayer:any;

   constructor(private mapService: MapService, private geocoder: GeocodingService) {}

   ngOnInit(): void {
console.log('tools component');
   }

   ngAfterViewInit() {

     let map = L.map("map", {
      zoomControl: false,
      center: L.latLng(4.418294, 108.224145),
      zoom: 6,
      minZoom: 4,
      maxZoom:22,
      layers: [this.mapService.baseMaps.OpenStreetMap]
  }).setView([3.1466, 101.6958], 6);


L.control.zoom({ position: "topright" }).addTo(map);
L.control.scale().addTo(map);

var customControl =  L.Control.extend({

  options: {
    position: 'bottomright'
  },

map.addControl(new customControl());

this.mapService.map = map;
    this.geocoder.getCurrentLocation()
        .subscribe(
            location => map.panTo([location.latitude, location.longitude]),
            err => console.error(err)
        );

toolbar
var drawnItems = L.featureGroup();
    map.addLayer(drawnItems);

    var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw(options);
    map.addControl(drawControl);

    map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function(e:any) {
        var layer = e.layer;

        drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
    });


  function afterRender(result:any) {
    return result;
  }

  function afterExport(result:any) {
    return result;
  }

  function downloadMap(caption:any) {
    var downloadOptions =   {
      caption: {
        text: caption,
        font: '30px Arial',
        fillStyle: 'black',
        position: [100,200]
      },
      exclude: ['.leaflet-control-zoom', '.leaflet-control-attribution'],
      format: 'image/jpeg',
      fileName: 'Map.jpg',
      afterRender: afterRender,
      afterExport: afterExport
  };
    var promise = map.downloadExport(downloadOptions);
    var data = promise.then(function(result:any){
       return result;
    });
    console.log(data)
    }

   }

  }
```

and this is my JS file

```
  L.Map.mergeOptions({ preferCanvas: true });
  if (!('exportError' in this)) {
    this.exportError = {
      wrongBeginSelector:,
      wrongEndSelector: ,
      jqueryNotAvailable: ,
      popupWindowBlocked: ,
      emptyFilename: 
    };
  }


  this.supportedCanvasMimeTypes = function() {
    if ('_supportedCanvasMimeTypes' in this) {
      return this._supportedCanvasMimeTypes;
    }
    var mimeTypes = {
      PNG:'image/png',
      JPEG: 'image/jpeg',
      JPG: 'image/jpg',
      GIF: 'image/gif',
      BMP: 'image/bmp',
      TIFF: 'image/tiff',
      XICON: 'image/x-icon',
      SVG: 'image/svg+xml',
      WEBP: 'image/webp'
    };
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.style.display = 'none';
    canvas = document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,1,1);
    this._supportedCanvasMimeTypes = {};
    for (var type in mimeTypes) {
      var mimeType = mimeTypes[type];
      var data = canvas.toDataURL(mimeType);
      var actualType = data.replace(/^data:([^;]*).*/, '$1');
      if (mimeType === actualType) {
        this._supportedCanvasMimeTypes[type] = mimeType;
      }
    }
    document.body.removeChild(canvas);
    return this._supportedCanvasMimeTypes;
  };

  this.export = function(options){
    var caption = {};
    var exclude = [];
    var format ='image/png';
    options = options || { caption: {}, exclude: []};
    if ('caption' in options) {
      caption = options['caption'];
      if ('position' in caption) {
        var position = caption.position;
        if (!Array.isArray(position)) {
          position = [0, 0];
        }
        if (position.length !=2 ) {
          if (position.length === 0){
            position[0] = 0;
          }
          if (position.length === 1 ) {
            position[1] = 0;
          }
        }
        if (typeof position[0] !== 'number') {
          if (typeof position[0] === 'string') {
            position[0] = parseInt(position[0]);
            if (isNaN(position[0])) {
              position[0] = 0;
            }
          }
        }
        if (typeof position[1] !== 'number') {
          if (typeof position[1] === 'string') {
            position[1] = parseInt(position[1]);
            if (isNaN(position[1])) {
              position[1] = 0;
            }
          }
        }
        caption.position = position;
      }
    }

    if ('exclude' in options && Array.isArray(options['exclude'])) {
      exclude = options['exclude'];
    }

    if ('format' in options) {
      format = options['format'];
    }

    var afterRender = options.afterRender;
    if (typeof afterRender !== 'function') {
      afterRender = function(result) {return result};
    }

    var afterExport = options.afterExport;
    if (typeof afterExport !== 'function') {
      afterExport = function(result) {return result};
    }

    var container = options.container || this._container;

    var hide = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < exclude.length; i++) {
      var selector = exclude[i];
      switch (typeof selector) {
        case 'object':
          if ('tagName' in selector) {  //DOM element
            hide.push(selector);
          }
          break;
        case 'string':  //selector
          var type = selector.substr(0,1);
          switch (type) {
            case '.': //class selector
              // var elements = container.getElementsByClassName(selector.substr(1));
              // for (var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
              //   hide.push(elements.item(j));
              // }
              break;
            case '#':   //id selector
              var element = container.getElementById(selector.substr(1));
              if (element) {
                hide.push(element);
              }
              break;
            case '$': //JQuery
              var jQuerySelector = selector.trim().substr(1);
              if (jQuerySelector.substr(0,1) !== '(') {
                throw new Error(this.exportError.wrongBeginSelector);
              }
              jQuerySelector = jQuerySelector.substr(1);
              if (jQuerySelector.substr(-1) !== ')') {
                throw new Error(this.exportError.wrongEndSelector);
              }
              jQuerySelector = jQuerySelector.substr(0, jQuerySelector.length-1);
              if (typeof jQuery !== 'undefined') {
                var elements = $(jQuerySelector, container);
                for (var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
                  hide.push(elements[i]);
                }
              } else {
                throw new Error(this.exportError.jqueryNotAvailable);
              }

          }
      }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < hide.length; i++) { //Hide exclude elements
      hide[i].setAttribute('data-html2canvas-ignore', 'true');
    }
    var _this = this;

    return html2canvas(container, {
      useCORS: true
    }).then(afterRender).then(
    function(canvas) {
      for (var i = 0; i < hide.length; i++) { //Unhide exclude elements
        hide[i].removeAttribute('data-html2canvas-ignore');
      }
      if ('text' in caption && caption.text) {
        var x, y;
        if ('position' in caption) {
          x = caption.position[0];
          y = caption.position[1];
        } else {
          x = 0;
          y = 0;
        }
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        if ('font' in caption) {
          ctx.font = caption.font;
        }
        if ('fillStyle' in caption) {
          ctx.fillStyle = caption.fillStyle;
        }
        ctx.fillText(caption.text,x , y);
      }

     //           document.body.appendChild(canvas);
      var ret = format === 'canvas' ? canvas : { data:canvas.toDataURL(format), width: canvas.width,  height: canvas.height, type: format};
      return ret;
    }, function(reason) {
      var newReason = reason;
      alert(reason);
    }).then(afterExport)
    ;
  };

  this.printExport = function(options) {
    var _this = this;

    return this.export(options).then(
      function(result) {
        var printWindow = window.open('', '_blank');
        if (printWindow) {
          var printDocument = printWindow.document;
          printDocument.write('<html><head><title>' + (options.text ? options.text : '') + '</title></head><body onload=\'window.print(); window.close();\'></body></html>');
          var img = printDocument.createElement('img');
          img.height = result.height;
          img.width = result.width;
          img.src = result.data;
          printDocument.body.appendChild(img);
          printDocument.close();
          printWindow.focus();
        } else {
          throw new Error(_this.exportError.popupWindowBlocked);
        }

        return result;
      }
    );
  };

  this.downloadExport = function(options) {
    if (!('fileName' in options)) {
      throw new Error(this.exportError.emptyFilename);
    }

    var fileName = options.fileName;
    delete options.fileName;
    return this.export(options).then(
      function(result) {
        var fileData = atob(result.data.split(',')[1]);
        var arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(fileData.length);
        var view = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
        for (var i = 0; i < fileData.length; i++) {
          view[i] = fileData.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff;
        }

        var blob;
        if (typeof Blob === 'function') {
          blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
        } else {
          var blobBuilder = new (window.BlobBuilder || window.WebKitBlobBuilder || window.MozBlobBuilder || window.MSBlobBuilder);
          blobBuilder.append(arrayBuffer);
          blob = blobBuilder.getBlob('application/octet-stream');
        }

        if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {

          window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
        } else {
          var blobUrl = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
          var downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
          downloadLink.style = 'display: none';
          downloadLink.download = fileName;
          downloadLink.href = blobUrl;

          document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
          downloadLink.click();
          document.body.removeChild(downloadLink);
        }

        return result;
      }
    );
  };
```

Comment: should you not be declaring it as 

declare function downloadExport(): any;

Comment: if i not declare downloadExport it comeout error downloadExport not define @Digvijay